# Pass through server / proxy

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, linux, apache

I'm looking for advice on how this can be done. I want to have a server sit in between the client and the actual server. For example:

```
Client -> Proxy Type Server -> Web Server.
```

So in return the web server would pass results to the proxy server which in return give the results back to the client. For example:

```
Client <- Proxy Type Server <- Web Server
```

Here is a diagram if it makes life easier:

[image: A diagram]

If it was just simple GET requests not a problem but I'm not sure how it would work if the client was posting data. I hope someone can advise me on this. Thank you if you can!

Comment: @Bruce May we know the reason you want such a structure?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question is... If you set up a proxy server between your client and the application server, then it will be just that: a proxy server. So it will proxy requests to the application server, just as you've shown in your diagram. If a client `POST`s data to the proxy, the proxy server will `POST` that same data to the application server and return the response to the client...

Are you asking *how* to set up something like this?

**EDIT:** I'm going to take a wild guess here...

> If it was just simple GET requests not a problem but I'm not sure how it would work if the client was posting data

Do you mean that the client is `POST`ing to *a PHP or Ruby script* on the "Proxy Server", and not an *actual* proxy server like Squid or Apache's `mod_proxy`? If so, are you asking how, using PHP, to send that POST data to the application server? If that's your question, here's the answer:

```
<?php

$application_server = '1.2.3.4'; // replace with IP or hostname of application server
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // you may need to change this, not sure from your question.

$curl = curl_init("http://{$application_server}{$uri}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$data = curl_exec($curl);

// do something with $data, transform it however you want...

echo $data;
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Yes but I need access to the results before sending on to the client.

Comment: What needs to access the results? What are you needing to do with the results? Can you edit your question and be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Josh, Sorry cant edit but I thought by adding the image I made it more obvious. But client requests the web site. The proxy server does the job at getting the request but I want to be able to look at the result and maybe even adjust it before sending back to the client. Does this help ?

Comment: You can edit by using the "edit" link under the question. What sort of parsing do you want to do? Let me know that and I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Hi Josh, OK so Curl is the answer !!. I will give that a go. Thank you very much.